# How Do I Browse for an Image and Display in Browser?

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, load

I feel like I'm pretty close.

What I want to be able to do is click a button, browse for a file and have it immediately display in the browser. So far- when I click the button, I can browse for my file but all I get in the browser is a broken image icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadImage()
{
        var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");

        document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myFiles.files.src +"'>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="files" type="file" name="files" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage();">
</div>
<div id="images">
Images will go here...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like it should be pretty simple but I can't seem to make it work. Can someone straighten me out? Thanks in advance!

[edit]
Thanks for your quick reply, user3030089!

I'm basing this off of a project that I had last semester at school. It did essentially what I want it to but it did it for an array. For what I'm doing right now, I just want one image- not an array so that I can get rid of those for loops and such.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadImage()
{
    myImages = new Array();
    var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");

    for (var i=0; i < myFiles.files.length; i++)
    {
        myImages[i] = myFiles.files[i].name;
    }

    var theImages = document.getElementById("images");
    theImages.innerHTML = ""; // Clearout the image area.

    for (var i=0; i < myFiles.files.length; i++)
    {
    "<img id='pic" + i + i + ";'" + " src='" + myImages[i] +
    "'" + " width = '400' " + " /> ";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" onchange="loadImage();" multiple />
</div>
<div id="images" style="position:relative; ">
Images will go here...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I want to do is simplify this so that it just works with one image.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons browsers do no allow this, ie JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System, however using HTML5 File API, only Firefox provides a mozFullPath property, but fortunately if you try to get the value it returns an empty string:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files[0].mozFullPath);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SCK5A/

So don't waste your time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please take a look at the edit.